# Class with two or more template overloads

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Suppose I had a class that I wanted to declare with two "overloads", one that accepted 1 template parameter and another that accepted 2 like the pseudo code below:

```
template <typename I>
class B {
public:
};


template <typename F, typename I>
class B { 
};
```

such that `B` can be instantiated with only 1 or 2 parameters:

```
B<int> hello;
B<int, int> hello2;
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `template <typename A, typename B = void>` (or some other placeholder instead of `void`), then partially specialize for `B == void`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
template <typename A, typename... Args> // ellipsis makes Args a
class B                                 // template parameter pack
{
public:
};

int main()
{
    B<int> hello;
    B<int, int> hello2;
    B<int, int, double> hello3;
}
```

Now `Args` is called a **template parameter pack**.

More specific to what you want:

```
template <typename F, typename I = int>
class B
{
public:
};

int main()
{
    B<int> hello;
    B<int, int> hello2;
}
```

This one allows a maximum of two template arguments.